# Rails ActiveRecord Association not autosaved on brand new instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am upgrading some legacy code from rails 5.0.7.2 (A) to 5.2.8.1 (B) and from Ruby 2.5.0 (A) to Ruby 2.7.7 (B).

In A the following seed file works fine (removed namespace for better readability):

```rb
def up
    Test.find_by(name: 'Rewarded_Ad_Goal').try(:destroy)
    choice_1565 = Choice.new(weight: 1, value: '0_Control')
    choice_1566 = Choice.new(weight: 1, value: '1_Alt')
    test = Test.create!(name: 'Rewarded_Ad_Goal', choices: [choice_1565, choice_1566], aasm_state: 'stopped')
end
```

Running the above statements manually in the rails console yields this output:

```
irb(main):002:0> choice_1565 = Choice.new(weight: 1, value: '0_Control')
=> #<Choice id: nil, test_id: nil, weight: 1, value: "0_Control", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):003:0> choice_1566 = Choice.new(weight: 1, value: '1_Alt')
=> #<Choice id: nil, test_id: nil, weight: 1, value: "1_Alt", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):004:0> test = Test.create!(name: 'Rewarded_Ad_Goal', choices: [choice_1565, choice_1566], aasm_state: 'stopped')
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Test Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingot_tests" WHERE "ingot_tests"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Rewarded_Ad_Goal"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (9.6ms)  INSERT INTO "ingot_choices" ("weight", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["weight", 1], ["value", "0_Control"], ["created_at", "2023-04-12 20:10:36.884181"], ["updated_at", "2023-04-12 20:10:36.884181"]]
  SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "ingot_tests" ("aasm_state", "default_choice_id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["aasm_state", "stopped"], ["default_choice_id", "662"], ["name", "Rewarded_Ad_Goal"], ["created_at", "2023-04-12 20:10:36.896752"], ["updated_at", "2023-04-12 20:10:36.896752"]]
  SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "ingot_choices" SET "test_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "ingot_choices"."id" = $3  [["test_id", 327], ["updated_at", "2023-04-12 20:10:36.901345"], ["id", 662]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "ingot_choices" ("test_id", "weight", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["test_id", 327], ["weight", 1], ["value", "1_Alt"], ["created_at", "2023-04-12 20:10:36.906051"], ["updated_at", "2023-04-12 20:10:36.906051"]]
   (6.3ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Test id: 327, ends_at: nil, starts_at: nil, aasm_state: "stopped", default_choice_id: "662", name: "Rewarded_Ad_Goal", created_at: "2023-04-12 20:10:36", updated_at: "2023-04-12 20:10:36">
```

The association that a Test has to a Choice is properly saved along with the parent object as one would expect with a has_many association.

When running the exact same seed file code in B it breaks with this error:

```
irb(main):004:0> test = Ingot::Test.create!(name: 'Rewarded_Ad_Goal', choices: [choice_1565, choice_1566], aasm_state: 'stopped')
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Ingot::Test Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingot_tests" WHERE "ingot_tests"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Rewarded_Ad_Goal"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Ingot::Test Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "ingot_tests" WHERE "ingot_tests"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Rewarded_Ad_Goal"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "ingot_tests" ("aasm_state", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["aasm_state", "stopped"], ["name", "Rewarded_Ad_Goal"], ["created_at", "2023-04-10 19:17:33.630832"], ["updated_at", "2023-04-10 19:17:33.630832"]]
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):4
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "default_choice_id" violates not-null constraint)
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (311, null, null, stopped, null, Rewarded_Ad_Goal, 2023-04-10 19:17:33.630832, 2023-04-10 19:17:33.630832).
: INSERT INTO "ingot_tests" ("aasm_state", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
```

See below for relevant model definitions:

**test.rb**

```rb
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    include AASM
    include Contracts

    belongs_to :default_choice, class_name: 'Ingot::Choice'
    has_many :assignments, class_name: 'Ingot::Assignment', dependent: :delete_all
    has_many :choices, class_name: 'Ingot::Choice', dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
    has_many :filters, class_name: 'Ingot::Filter', dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :default_choice,
      allow_destroy: true,
      reject_if: :all_blank

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices,
      allow_destroy: true,
      reject_if: :all_blank

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :filters,
      allow_destroy: true,
      reject_if: :all_blank

    validates_length_of :choices, minimum: 2, message: 'are missing.  You must specify at least two alternatives.'
    validates_presence_of :default_choice
    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_uniqueness_of :name

    before_validation :set_default_choice,
      unless: :default_choice
...

    def set_default_choice # confirmed this gets called
      puts "Setting default choice to #{choices.first.id}" # <== nil
      puts "Setting default choice to #{choices.first.weight}"
      puts "Setting default choice to #{choices.first.value}"
      puts "Setting default choice to #{choices.first.test_id}" # <== nil
      self.default_choice ||= choices.first
    end
end
```

**choice.rb**

```rb
class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :test, class_name: 'Ingot::Test'
    has_many :assignments, class_name: 'Ingot::Assignment', dependent: :destroy

    validates_numericality_of :weight
    validates_presence_of :value
    validates_presence_of :weight

    before_validation :set_default_weight

    def test
      super || Test.where(default_choice_id: id).first
    end

    private

    def set_default_weight
      self.weight ||= 1
    end
  end
```

The Choices don't seem to be saved anymore in B while they were in A. Were there any major changes between A & B? I haven't been able to find anything to explain this behaviour and all the callbacks within the ActiveRecord models still seem to work which set the default choice (the print statements show the hook is reached but the choices are not yet saved as they have no `id` or `test_id`).

Comment: Seems like `Test` requires a `default_choice` to be set, but your `up` method doesn't set it.

Comment: The callback `before_validation :set_default_choice` sets the default choice. It just doesn't seem to have an id yet as it was never persisted by the ORM in B. No code was changed between upgrading rails/ruby.

Comment: But that doesn't work because at the time of validation those choices have not been saved into the database and therefore their `id` are still `nil`. You might what to try `before_save` instead.

Comment: @spickermann I see, i can give that a try. Any idea why it would work in the older rails (A) but not the newer one (B)?

Comment: The order of insert into the database changed. A saves a choice first and then the test, B saves the test first.

Comment: @spickermann tried with `before_save` and had to remove a bunch of validations but still couldn't get it to persist correctly. Seems i will have to rewrite tonnes of code to handle this completely breaking change between 2 minor versions of Rails which seems to not be documented at all :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253125/discussion-between-spickermann-and-pragmaticprogrammer).